# Group data.table by continuity of variable

Tags: r, data.table

I want to separate a `data.table` into groups based on the continuity of one variable.
So to speak, from this `data.table`:

```
DT <- data.table(Var1 = c(1:5, 7:10))
```

I want it to be grouped like this:

```
#    Var1 group
# 1:    1     1 # 1 to 5 is continuous with a maximal difference of 1
# 2:    2     1
# 3:    3     1
# 4:    4     1
# 5:    5     1
# 6:    7     2 # 6 to 10 is continuous again
# 7:    8     2
# 8:    9     2
# 9:   10     2
```

The difference of `Var1` should not be limited to one like in this minimal example, but be adjustable, so that `DT <- data.table(Var1 = c(seq(1,10, 2), seq(13,30, 2)))` will also be separated into two groups when given a maximal difference of 2.

EDIT:
I should clarify that a 'maximal difference' of 2 or more is meant in a way that differences in `Var1` smaller than two should be treated as 'continuous'. Furthermore the variable `Var1` should not be limited to integer values. The last thing could be avoided by multiplying e.g. 0.14 by 100 to get 14 and also multiplying 'maximal difference' by 100.

Comment: Maybe use round? `round(c(1:5, 7:10), -1)`

Comment: ``round`` does not work for the 2nd example, see: ``data.frame(Var1 = c(seq(1,10, 2), seq(13,30, 2)), Var2 = round(c(seq(1,10, 2), seq(13,30, 2)), -1))``, but it is an interesting solution for the simple problem.

Comment: `cumsum(c(0, diff(df$Var1)!= 1))` ?? For second case, `cumsum(c(0, diff(df$Var1)!= 2))`

Comment: Based on your comments and answers I found a full answer myself (but it seems strange to answer the question myself, as it wasn't possible without your assistance): ``DT$group <- cumsum(DT[, c(0, ifelse(diff(Var1) > 2, 1, 0))])``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DT[, group := rleid(cumprod(c(1, diff(Var1))))]
#   Var1 group
#1:    1     1
#2:    2     1
#3:    3     1
#4:    4     1
#5:    5     1
#6:    7     2
#7:    8     2
#8:    9     2
#9:   10     2

step <- 2
DT <- data.table(Var1 = c(seq(1,10, 2), seq(13,30, 2)))
DT[, group := rleid(cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(Var1) != step)))]
#    Var1 group
# 1:    1     1
# 2:    3     1
# 3:    5     1
# 4:    7     1
# 5:    9     1
# 6:   13     2
# 7:   15     2
# 8:   17     2
# 9:   19     2
#10:   21     2
#11:   23     2
#12:   25     2
#13:   27     2
#14:   29     2
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works for the first example. Can you edit the solution for differences greater 1 like in my 2nd example?

Comment: This solution works quite well! For my needs of differences smaller equal 2 (or other values), I have to set ``>step``.

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution.

```
foo <- function(x){
 gr <- which(!(duplicated(diff(x)) | duplicated(diff(x), fromLast = T)))
 if(length(gr) == 1){
   cbind(Var1=x,group=rep(1:(length(gr)+1), c(min(gr),length(x)-max(gr))))
 }else{
   cbind(Var1=x,group=rep(1:(length(gr)+1), c(min(gr), diff(gr),length(x)-max(gr))))
 }
}
```

All kind of differences are working.

```
foo(c(seq(1,10, 2), seq(13,30, 2)))
      Var1 group
 [1,]    1     1
 [2,]    3     1
 [3,]    5     1
 [4,]    7     1
 [5,]    9     1
 [6,]   13     2
 [7,]   15     2
 [8,]   17     2
 [9,]   19     2
[10,]   21     2
[11,]   23     2
[12,]   25     2
[13,]   27     2
[14,]   29     2
```

Three groups are working as well.

```
foo(c(1:5, 7:10, 13:20))
      Var1 group
 [1,]    1     1
 [2,]    2     1
 [3,]    3     1
 [4,]    4     1
 [5,]    5     1
 [6,]    7     2
 [7,]    8     2
 [8,]    9     2
 [9,]   10     2
[10,]   13     3
[11,]   14     3
[12,]   15     3
[13,]   16     3
[14,]   17     3
[15,]   18     3
[16,]   19     3
[17,]   20     3
```

For a `data.table` you can try:

```
foo <- function(x){
 gr <- which(!(duplicated(diff(x)) | duplicated(diff(x), fromLast = T)))
 if(length(gr) == 1){
   rep(1:(length(gr)+1), c(min(gr),length(x)-max(gr)))
 }else{
   rep(1:(length(gr)+1), c(min(gr), diff(gr),length(x)-max(gr)))
 }
}
DT[, group := foo(Var1)]
```

Comment: For a ``data.table(Var1 = c(1,2,3,5,  8,10,12,  17,18,20))`` I get an error message. The maximal difference here is considered to be 2, so that the group is ``c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)``